# ASP.NET 5 (MVC6) EF7 Foreign Key may cause cycles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Here are my models:

```cs
public class Post
{

    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(140)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }


    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

I am getting the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comment_Post_PostId' on table 'Comment' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is exactly how it is demonstrated in their [documents](https://readthedocs.com/projects/aspnet-ef/downloads/pdf/latest/).

Now if I remove:

```cs
[Required]
public int PostId { get; set; }
```

and use Fluent API as follows:

```cs
builder.Entity<Comment>().HasOne(p => p.Post).WithMany(c => c.Comments).IsRequired();
```

I still get the same error. If I explicitly state

```cs
builder.Entity<Comment>().HasOne(p => p.Post).WithMany(c => c.Comments).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I still get the same error.

If I use the following:

```cs
builder.Entity<Comment>().HasOne(p => p.Post).WithMany(c => c.Comments);
```

A comment can be entered without a Post. A comment must belong to a post.

Am I missing something? This is a common use case, a 1 to many relationship with a required FK to a PK.

Comment: Also, note that ApplicationUser is setup the same way. But those columns get setup properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was indeed missing something. My structure is that a User can have a Post. A Post can have Comments. Since a Comment also has a User, this is what was causing the cyclic issue.

When a Post is deleted it will cascade delete the Comment. Which is what we want.

When a User is deleted, it would cascade the delete to a Post and a Comment. But a Post will also attempt to cascade delete to Comment.

The solution I used was to remove the cascade delete from User to Comment.

This is done by the following:

```
builder.Entity<Comment>().HasOne(c => c.ApplicationUser).WithMany(u => u.Comments).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```